# HTTPS Login using Java

Tags: java, authentication, https

I've a problem to login to a website via `https`.
I wrote this code (it works) for http access:

```
String user = user;
String password = psw;    

String authString = user + ":" + password;
byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);

URLConnection connection= url.openConnection();

connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);  
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

connection.connect();
```

I'd like to do the same things but via `https`. Is it possible?

Comment: Is the problem with certificates?

Answer (score 0):

You can, please use

```
HttpsURLConnection
```

Checkout sample program on http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-https-client-httpsurlconnection-example/

Comment: Please refrain from link-only answers.

Answer (score 0):

When specifying your URL, make sure to pass "https://..."

```
url.openConnection();
```

will return you an object that has the type of the established connection. It will always be URLConnection, but it can be a class that extends URLConnection as well. Such classes are HttpURLConnection and *HttpsURLConnection* (and others).

You should verify that the returned object is of type HttpsURLConnection. And if it's not, you should stop the connection (in case you want to avoid non secure connections).

```
if (connection instanceof HttpsURLConnection)
```